# How to align crystal report from right to left

Tags: css, .net, crystal-reports, report

i am using crystal reports with visual studio 2013. i used cross tab report to show data, the problem is i have data in URDU language which starts from right to left but when i put data in cross tab it increases from left to right and i want cross tab should increase its length from right to left. i tried but did not find any way to do it. 
so how can i achieve this .
i want this

[image]

instead of this
[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Paulie_D

Comment: Have you tried going to format for a individual cell?

Comment: By the way its a valid question no down voting required

Comment: This isn't even a programming question. But a "How do I use software X which might be used from code but Im not doing that in this case" question. Shame on you for answering Siva.

Answer (score 4):

you can do It by right click and format and then selecting right to left instead of left to right.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can loop against report object and change location of it
Example :

```
private void SetLocationOfLineObject(ReportObject fild)
{
   fild.Left = rptAcc1.PrintOptions.PageContentWidth - (fild.Left  );
}
```